# Simple sum gives complicated answer

Tags: summation

If $a$ is real and $b$ is complex, then this sum is easy to do by hand:

```
Sum[E^(I n a)/(n + b), {n, -∞, ∞}]
```

> `E^(-I a b) (I a+π Cot[b π]+Log[1-E^(-I a)]-Log[1-E^(I a)])`

whereas Mathematica gives a more complicated answer:

```
(* -E^(-I a) HurwitzLerchPhi[E^(-I a),1,1-b] + HurwitzLerchPhi[E^(I a),1,b] *)
```

How can I convince Mathematica to give me a simpler result without involving special functions (ie. `HurwitzLerchPhi`)?

Comment: They give the same numerical answer.  What is the problem?

Comment: Actually what you call complicated answer is simpler. It has leaf count of 43 while the one you gave has leaf count of 47. So your answer is more complicated :)  Also the Czech mathematician Mathias Lerch will not be happy to hear you say that his function is useless.

Comment: My answer is an elementary transcendental function whereas Lerchphi is a non elementary transcendental function. Huge difference.

Comment: If you plot them, you see that they are similar but not identical. HurwithLerchPhi has some branch cuts:
`ComplexPlot3D[With[{a=0.4},E^(-I a b) (I a+\[Pi] Cot[b \[Pi]]+Log[1-E^(-I a)]-Log[1-E^(I a)])],{b,-5-5I,5+5I}]
ComplexPlot3D[With[{a=0.4},E^(-I a) (-HurwitzLerchPhi[E^(-I a),1,1-b]+E^(I a) HurwitzLerchPhi[E^(I a),1,b])],{b,-5-5I,5+5I}]`

Comment: To add: Yes, so for a=0 the sum does not converge. When you take the limit of your result to a -> 0 it will find 0 as result. But the limit of a -> 0 for the HurwitzLerchPhi result gives Indeterminate. So there are some differences between them, and I would say that the HurwithLerchPhi is more precisely handles branch cuts…